# How to parallel for-loop in python?

Tags: python, matrix, parallel-processing, gpu, matrix-factorization

## Update 1.0 start

It seems when call

```
for i, Wi in enumerate(W.T):
    idx.append(i)
    result.append(pool.apply_async(ALS_Y, (X, Wi, Q, lambda_, n_factors, i,)))
```

the arguments passed into the function `ALS_Y/ALS_X` are not references, it copied the arguments..So, when `X` or `Y`is very `large matrixes`, such as, in my case, it's `6000*40` or so(And it's a `for-loop`, let's assume the number iterations is `50 000`, so ...), it exceeds the limit of memory.
And then I tried using global arguments, just passing the indices as parameters into the functions,

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import numpy as np

def func(idx):
    global a
    a[idx] += 1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    a=range(10)
    for j in xrange(2):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
        result = []
        for i in xrange(10):
            result.append(pool.apply_async(func, (i, )))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print a
        print "Sub-process(es) done."
```

it outputs: `

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Sub-process(es) done.
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Sub-process(es) done.
```

`So, this means it still copied`a`!
Now, I wonder is there any way to handler this issue? Appreciate!

## Update 1.0 end

---

Below is my code in python to solve the matrix factorization problem.
W = XY. However, the codes below is not efficient, and I hope that it can be converted into parallel version, using GPU is the best, CPU is also fine. I am have no experience about parallel programming, so is there anybody can give me some advice?

Below is the code to factorize the matrix using ALS (alternating least square, details [here](http://bugra.github.io/work/notes/2014-04-19/alternating-least-squares-method-for-collaborative-filtering/))

```
for ii in range(n_iterations):
    for u, Wu in enumerate(W):
        X[u] = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(Y, np.dot(np.diag(Wu), Y.T)) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors),
                               np.dot(Y, np.dot(np.diag(Wu), Q[u].T))).T #X_inner loop

    for i, Wi in enumerate(W.T):
        Y[:,i] = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), X)) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors), #Y_inner loop
                                 np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), Q[:, i])))#Y_inner loop
    error = get_error(Q, X, Y, W)
    weighted_errors.append(error)
    print '{}th iteration is completed'.format(ii)
```

**After used multiprocessing lib, my code now:**

```
def ALS_X(Y, Wu, Q, lambda_, n_factors, u):
return np.linalg.solve(np.dot(Y, np.dot(np.diag(Wu), Y.T)) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors),
                           np.dot(Y, np.dot(np.diag(Wu), Q[u].T))).T  

for ii in range(n_iterations):
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12)#create pool
result = []#store each row for X
idx = []#store the row number
for u, Wu in enumerate(W):
    idx.append(u)
    result.append(pool.apply_async(ALS_X, (Y, Wu, Q, lambda_, n_factors, u,)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
for u, vector in zip(idx, result):
    X[u] = vector.get()#assign the result to X
######################################
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12)#for Y, much similar to X
result = []
idx = []
for i, Wi in enumerate(W.T):
    idx.append(i)
    result.append(pool.apply_async(ALS_Y, (X, Wi, Q, lambda_, n_factors, i,)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
for i, vector in zip(idx, result):
    Y[:,i]  = vector.get()
error = get_error(Q, X, Y, W)
weighted_errors.append(error)
print '{}th iteration is completed'.format(ii), 'error: ',error
```

**But somewhat misery, the program always crashed silently...**

Below is the whole bunch of my code.. it's all in messy. JUST ignore `load_data` `get_error` and `vec2str`, since here I generate the matrix randomly..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def vec2str(vec):
    res = ''
    for dim in len(vec):
        res += str(vec[dim]) + ','
    return res

def load_data(heads, filename, sep,header=None):
    data = pd.read_table(filename, sep=sep, header=header, names=heads)
    rp = data.pivot_table(columns=['sid'],index=['uid'],values=['rating'])#not generally...
    Q = rp.fillna(0)
    Q = Q.values
    W = Q >0.5
    W[W == True] = 1
    W[W == False] = 0
    W = W.astype(np.float64, copy=False)
    return Q, W, rp

def get_error(Q, X, Y, W):
    return np.sum((W * (Q - np.dot(X, Y)))**2)

'''
X[u] = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(, np.dot(np.diag(), .T)) +  * np.eye(),
                               np.dot(, np.dot(np.diag(), Q[u].T))).T
'''
def ALS_X(Y, Wu, Q, lambda_, n_factors, u):
    return np.linalg.solve(np.dot(Y, np.dot(np.diag(Wu), Y.T)) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors),
                               np.dot(Y, np.dot(np.diag(Wu), Q[u].T))).T

'''
Y[:,i] = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), X)) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors),
                                 np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), Q[:, i])))
'''

def ALS_Y(X, Wi, Q, lambda_, n_factors, i):
    return np.linalg.solve(np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), X)) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors),
                                 np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), Q[:, i])))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    lambda_ = 0.1
    n_factors = 40
    filename = 'data_songID'
    n_iterations = 20
    #Q, W, rp = load_data(['uid', 'sid', 'rating'], filename, ',')
    Q = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
    m, n = Q.shape
    W = np.eye(1000)
    print 'Loading data finished, ', 'size: ', Q.shape
    print 'Settings ', 'lambda = {}'.format(lambda_), 'n_factors = {}'.format(n_factors)
    X = 5 * np.random.rand(m, n_factors) 
    Y = 5 * np.random.rand(n_factors, n)
    errors = []
    for ii in range(n_iterations):
        X = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(Y, Y.T) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors), 
                        np.dot(Y, Q.T)).T
        Y = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(X.T, X) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors),
                        np.dot(X.T, Q))
        if ii % 100 == 0:
            print('{}th iteration is completed'.format(ii))
        errors.append(get_error(Q, X, Y, W))
        Q_hat = np.dot(X, Y)
        print('Error of rated movies: {}'.format(get_error(Q, X, Y, W)))
    print errors
    #####ALS start....#####
    print '*'*100
    weighted_errors = []
    for ii in range(n_iterations):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12)
        result = []
        idx = []
        for u, Wu in enumerate(W):
            idx.append(u)
            result.append(pool.apply_async(ALS_X, (Y, Wu, Q, lambda_, n_factors, u,)))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        for u, vector in zip(idx, result):
            X[u] = vector.get()
        ######################################
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12)
        result = []
        idx = []
        for i, Wi in enumerate(W.T):
            idx.append(i)
            result.append(pool.apply_async(ALS_Y, (X, Wi, Q, lambda_, n_factors, i,)))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        for i, vector in zip(idx, result):
            Y[:,i]  = vector.get()
        error = get_error(Q, X, Y, W)
        weighted_errors.append(error)
        print '{}th iteration is completed'.format(ii), 'error: ',error

    weighted_Q_hat = np.dot(X,Y)
    print weighted_errors
    X.tofile('X.bin')
    Y.tofile('Y.bin')
    latent_user_file = open('user_latent','w')
    for idx in len(rp.axes[0]):
        latent_user_file.write(str(rp.axes[0][idx]) + '\t' + vec2str(X[idx,:]) + '\n')

    latent_mid_file = open('mid_latent', 'w')
    for idx in len(rp.axes[1]):
        latent_mid_file.write(str(rp.axes[1][idx]) + '\t' + vec2str(Y.T[idx,:]) + '\n')
```

Comment: why don't you create 2 threads using multithreading module and then join them

Comment: @binayr: Threads in Python are subject to the Global Interpreter Lock, but a C extension like NumPy may be able to do meaningful amounts of work without holding the GIL, so it's difficult to say how much help that would be.

Comment: Since Y_inner loop has to be executed after X_inner loop. But each iteration in  X_inner loop can be executed simultaneously. And I hope that the X_inner loop can be executed parallel... My machine is a 12-CPU and 3-GPU... So, I hope that I can fully utilize these, but I am not so clear about how to do that.. sad..

Comment: @Kevin Holding the GIL is a problem in python 2.7 and in Thread Module, However it's optimized in Threading module, where you do not have to care about the GIL. Numpy is also a good option.

Comment: @binayr: "where you do not have to care about the GIL" - What?  While Python does manage the GIL for you, it is certainly not the case that you can ignore its performance impact.  *Any* execution of Python bytecode requires holding the GIL.  (Almost) any call into the Python/C API requires holding the GIL.  Splitting CPU-bound pure Python code between two threads will slow it down since you have the overhead of context switching between the threads and no actual performance boost.

Comment: OP: You might get better responses on [codereview.SE] instead of here.

Comment: @Kevin I agree every call to Python api requires holding the GIL, But Unlike Thread Module, developer don't need to manually handle the GIL in Threading module. You can simply start a new thread and join them and don't need to worry about race condition and locking of GIL.

Comment: @binayr: Yes, I agree, Python does handle the GIL for you.  But it cannot bypass the fundamental limitation that only one thread can execute Python bytecode at once.  If you're spending a lot of time executing Python bytecode, multiple threads will do *nothing* for your performance.

Comment: @Kevin Yes python executes only 1 thread at once, correct. But using multithreading it makes it asynchronous. The second loop will not wait for the first loop to complete as it does in usual python code. If you really want to execute everything in parallel you can use multiprocessing and utilize all cores you have.But they will not share same information and they will be running in different core.

Comment: @binayr: Since OP is doing CPU-bound code and never said anything about multiprocessing, I fail to see how any of that is relevant to *this* question.

Comment: @AlecWang I suggest use `muliprocessing` module with `apply_async` for running pool of parallel processes. If you need some examples let me know.

Comment: @binayr: what you describe does not occur in the `threading` module (subject to GIL limitations) but in the `multiprocessing` one. The latter shares the same interface with the former but uses true processes instead of threads - which may causes other problems...

Comment: multiprocessing lib ALARMING....., It crashed...OH JESUS!

Comment: there is so much misinformation and just plain wrong advice and confusion in the comments, kind of proves this is off-topic.